# dotnet core - rest API + SQL server - possible to go not MVC (only controller?)

Tags: .net-core

I am struggling here with doing proof of concepts in C# and dotnet core, I actually like dotnet core and wish I could implement my API Server in it (api server that is doing jobs on a database).

But one thing that really gets to me when developing in proof of concept where database changes all the time and code needs to get updated with ping pong to REST clients is that it seems I need to follow MVC structure (or MxC as there's really no view).

Isn't it possible to create a controller only so all my code including accessing my database; I don't want to create a model first, I will hardcode the names first as things in POC phase changes constantly. Then sometime in the end it can be converted into a MVC structure.

A bit similar to when I'm doing APIs in Python or Node.js - you are free to write the code completely in the controller and can work directly with json deserialization instead needing to maintain both models and controller.

I am seeking an example of doing all in controller towards a SQL server (ex. api /GetAll) - will perform "select * from dbo.allcars" and return that - only in the controller function.

(Even though I am a beginner I really don't want to conform to the MVC as it takes out development time here in the proof of concept phase).

Comment: I think this blog covers the parts you need https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/database-first-in-net-core-2-0-crud-operation-part-one/

Comment: It creates models too and tie the database into the model. i would like to only deal with the json params/body/headers in the controller and then in the controller directly start working without having to have a model defined ( i know MS wants its split up but for rapid development here i would like avoid it )

Comment: you can simply get json results from sql server and output that in your controller.